# I'm trying to find the three angles of the face of a person, based on a 2D image by landmark

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find the yaw angles of the face of a person, based on a 2D image by the landmark
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HapYo.png)

I'm using dlib detect face,landmark.But I don't found any geometric method that can help me to find the angles X, Y and Z (Roll, Pitch and Yaw).

Could someone help me showing some method in python that works?

Comment: if you got a 3d point cloud model, you can project your dlib landmarks once on it (to get 3d landmarks), and later use cv2.solvePnp() with the current landmarks, to get rvec and tvec. it's called [POSIT](http://nullege.com/codes/search/opencv.posit)

Comment: how got a 3d point cloud model?? and project?

Comment: OP, did you find a solution?